# MasterDetail Hamburger Menu disappearing on back button pressed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, prism

I've created a simple Xamarin.Forms application with Prism to experiment with the navigation. I have taken the example application an changed it slightly.

When the application loads and the user logs in the application goes to the Master Detail page through 
 NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/Index/Navigation/Process"). On this page there is a button that does NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondProcess"). At this point the back button appears as expected but when it is pressed the app goes to the Process page and the hamburger menu is lost.

Am I using the navigation process incorrectly?

Edit:
I've uploaded the project to GitHub.
https://github.com/JonathanTurnerTBA/PrismExample.git

Comment: It appears this question has already been answered, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216358/hamburger-menu-prism-xamarin-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hamburger menu prism xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216358/hamburger-menu-prism-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I looked at the linked item and couldn't resolve my issue. I've added a GitHub repo to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> At this point the back button appears as expected but when it is pressed the app goes to the Process page and the hamburger menu is lost.

The problem is you passed the `Navigation Path` is incomplete. For your design requirement, the `MasterDetailPage` is the root navigation, if you want to display the hamburg menu in the per page, you need to modify the navigation path like the following:

```
"/Index/Navigation/ProcessList/FirstProcess"
```

When you press back button, the `NavigationService` will found the previous page `/Index/Navigation/ProcessList`, and attach *hamburg menu* automatically.